# Can you identify this modified plate?

Tags: part-identification

A friend asked me to identify an element, but I have no idea either. Customary search on BrickLink modified bricks/plates/tiles categories didn't give results.
I do not have any additional information besides this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like 
[Plate, Modified 2 x 8 with Door Rail](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30586#T=C) in yellow.

It's not easy to find because you would think it's a 1x8 plate modified rather than a 2x8.

Additional link: [Plate, Modified 2 x 8 with Door Rail](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30586/plate-special-2-x-8-with-door-rail/) at rebrickable.

Comment: Also, looked over it because it's in black... just a smudge on my cellphone for my poor old eyes